# Time-stamped file recording joystick button presses

Tags: autohotkey, joystick

This is for an experiment we are running in our lab.  First the script asks for a participant number and creates a file in C: .  During the experiment a participant with a gamepad presses a single button (8), and each time the button is pressed the file is written with the current time.  The q button returns a quit message and ends the script.

And it does not work.  I think the issue surrounds the joystick.  Any help much appreciated.

```
FormatTime, timestamp, , yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm
JoystickNumber = 1      
#SingleInstance
#persistent

InputBox, ssnum, Subject Number, Please enter the participant number
if ErrorLevel
    ExitApp
else
thefilename=%ssnum%_T_%timestamp%
    FileAppend,
        (
            %ssnum%%timestamp%
        ), C:\%thefilename%.txt
    return

Loop
{
GetKeyState, state, Joy8
    if state = D
        FileAppend,
        (
            %timestamp%, 
        ), C:\%thefilename%.txt
}

q::
MsgBox Exiting.  Your data is saved in the C drive as %thefilename%.txt
ExitApp
```

Comment: Should this output a file for each time the key is pressed, or have a log file that shows all the timestamps of when the key was pressed?

Comment: This is my error.   C:\%thefilename%.txt is actually written.

Comment: It looks like you are hitting a `return` before hitting your loop. I'll post my suggestions as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you are hitting a `return` before it even reaches your loop.

I've cleaned up your code a bit as well as turned your loop into a hotkey. This will prevent multiple writes to the file if the key is held.  If you need to count holding of the button, you can use the loop you had.

```
FormatTime, timestamp, , yyyy_MM_dd_HH_mm
JoystickNumber = 1      
#SingleInstance
#Persistent

InputBox, ssnum, Subject Number, Please enter the participant number
if ErrorLevel
    ExitApp

thefilename = C:\%ssnum%_T_%timestamp%.txt
FileAppend, %ssnum%`t%timestamp%`n, %thefilename%

~Joy8::
    FormatTime, timestamp, , HH:mm:ss
    FileAppend, %timestamp%`n, %thefilename%
Return

q::
    MsgBox Exiting.  Your data is saved in the C drive as %thefilename%
    Run % thefilename
    ExitApp
```